# SQL SERVER with VS2010 Login

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, authentication

```
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=&quot;Localhost\SQLEXPRESS&quot;;
         Initial Catalog=Saqib;Integrated Security=SSPI;
         AttachDBFilename=|D:\SAQIB|\aspnetdb.mdf;
         User Instance=true; User ID=sa;Password=angel"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I create a `connectionstring` to access localhost database. My code is below please suggest me that is it correct or not? Because when I run my login page on the browser it give this error:

```
Server Error in '/SAQIB1' Application.
Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you specify the db filename, you would use the |DataDirectory| placeholder. Its a substitution string used to denote the location of your db file like so:

```
"AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|database.mdf;"
```

In your case, you are specifying your own value and not using DataDirectory, so exclude the | characters and your setting would be:

```
AttachDBFilename=D:\SAQIB\aspnetdb.mdf;
```

Comment: There is same error after place |DataDirectory|
My Database File Name is Saqib and its .mdf file name is also saqib

Comment: Use this: AttachDBFilename=D:\SAQIB\aspnetdb.mdf;  Just remove the | characters

Comment: AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|D:\SAQIB\saqib.mdf;
Like This?

Comment: No use this  AttachDBFilename=D:\SAQIB\saqib.mdf;

Comment: and is it necessary that my sql server is also running when i make a connection?

Comment: Now I am facing This Error
Server Error in '/SAQIB1' Application.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Your connection string needs amending: connectionString="data source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;
         Initial Catalog=Saqib;Integrated Security=SSPI;
         AttachDBFilename=D:\SAQIB\saqib.mdf;
         User Instance=true;User ID=sa;Password=angel"

Comment: Thanks Reubz :) Thanks Alott :)